# Changing the desktop/background of the login screen (Win2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, login, desktop

I've got a couple of Window 2003 servers that I administer.

When logining in, users are presented with a default  grey background.  I'd like to change this to a different colour.

I've found references on Google to the `Hkey_Users\.Default\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper` registry key.  But we use these machine via RDP and I don't want to use an image, merely change the colour.

Is this possible?  If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a .reg something like this (tested it and it works):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Colors]
"Background"="0 78 152"
```

The values are 0-255 decimal in RGB order, so 255 0 0 would be bright red, for example.